# Where can I import the ServerBuild Type from Remix?

Tags: typescript, remix.run

I'm just setting up a Remix project from scratch. Here is my `server.ts` file

[image]

At line 9 it's complaining about the type of `build`.

```
Type 'type of import(...build/index) is not assignable to type 'ServerBuild'. The types of 'entry.module' are incompatible between these types.
```

My understanding is that `createRequestHandler` is expecting `build` to be of type `ServerBuild` but `build` is imported from a JS file.

Where can I import `ServerBuild` type and how can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Set the build type to ServerBuild

```
import { createRequestHandler } from '@remix-run/express';
import { broadcastDevReady, type ServerBuild } from '@remix-run/node';
import * as build from './build/index.js';

const serverBuild = build as unknown as ServerBuild;
app.all('*', createRequestHandler({ build: serverBuild }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { type ServerBuild } from '@remix-run/node'
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel the pain, I'm also trying to get a full typescript express+remix project to work.

Instead of importing the build folder like you do in that one line, try to mimic what they do in JavaScript here (this is from the express remix template):
https://github.com/Leejjon/my-remix-run/blob/main/server.js

This conversion to TypeScript attempt below worked for me:

```
import express, {Application} from 'express';
import { createRequestHandler } from "@remix-run/express";

import {type ServerBuild} from "@remix-run/server-runtime";
import path from "node:path";
import fs from "node:fs";
import url from "node:url";

const app: Application = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#at-a-minimum-disable-x-powered-by-header
app.disable("x-powered-by");

const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve("./build/index.js");
const VERSION_PATH = path.resolve("./build/version.txt");

// Remix fingerprints its assets so we can cache forever.
app.use(
    "/build",
    express.static("public/build", { immutable: true, maxAge: "1y" })
);

// Everything else (like favicon.ico) is cached for an hour. You may want to be
// more aggressive with this caching.
app.use(express.static("public", { maxAge: "1h" }));

const initialBuild: ServerBuild = await reimportServer();

app.all("*", createRequestHandler({
   build: initialBuild,
   mode: initialBuild.mode,
}));

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${port} !`);
});

/**
 * @returns {Promise<ServerBuild>}
 */
async function reimportServer() {
    const stat = fs.statSync(BUILD_PATH);

    // convert build path to URL for Windows compatibility with dynamic `import`
    const BUILD_URL = url.pathToFileURL(BUILD_PATH).href;

    // use a timestamp query parameter to bust the import cache
    return import(BUILD_URL + "?t=" + stat.mtimeMs);
}
```

I left out the chokidar stuff, so this doesn't have HMR.